# Spark application development on local cluster by IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark, hive, cloudera

I tried many things to execute the application on local cluster. However it did not work.

I am using CDH 5.7 and spark version is 1.6.
I am trying to create dataframe from hive on CDH 5.7.

If I use spark-shell, all codes works really well. However, I have no idea how can I set my intellJ configuration for efficient development environment.

Here is my code;

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object DataFrame {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello DataFrame")

    val conf = new SparkConf() // skip loading external settingg
      .setMaster("local") // could be "local[4]" for 4 threads
      .setAppName("DataFrame-Example")
      .set("spark.logConf", "true")


    val sc = new SparkContext(conf) 
    sc.setLogLevel("WARN") 
    println(s"Running Spark Version ${sc.version}")

    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
    sqlContext.sql("From src select key, value").collect().foreach(println)

  }
}
```

When I run this program on IntelliJ, the error messages are following;

```
Hello DataFrame
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/05/29 11:30:57 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
Running Spark Version 1.6.0
16/05/29 11:31:02 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.1.0
16/05/29 11:31:02 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:249)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive(HiveContext.scala:239)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$2.<init>(HiveContext.scala:459)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.catalog$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:459)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.catalog(HiveContext.scala:458)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$3.<init>(HiveContext.scala:475)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.analyzer$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:475)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.analyzer(HiveContext.scala:474)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:34)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:133)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:817)
at org.corus.spark.example.DataFrame$.main(DataFrame.scala:25)
at org.corus.spark.example.DataFrame.main(DataFrame.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx------
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:539)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:194)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx------
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:624)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:573)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:517)
... 25 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is there anyone know a solution?
Thanks.

I found several resources about this problem. But none of them did not work.
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/develop-apache-spark-apps-intellij-idea-windows-os-samuel-yee
https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/06/how-to-create-an-intellij-idea-project-for-apache-hadoop/

Comment: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx------.  change the permissions of that directory to 777. `chmod 777 /tmp/hive`

Comment: Running hive/CDH locally is too heavy, TBH. I sometimes run spark (just brew install apache-spark) locally just to read some csv files to test some ideas. You can still create a dataframe from that and do whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks Gangaraju. However, it did not work. Because I would like to use installed Hive(remote) from compiled spark program.

Comment: @piggybox I also would like to run spark locally instead of load data from remote Hive. Is there any idea? Thanks.

Comment: @JS.Park check out the "Self-Contained Applications" section in Spark doc (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html) and if your IDEA has the scala plugin should be able to load the sbt project properly. Once you package (`sbt package`) the your project into a jar then just submit this to spark locally (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

Comment: Thanks all. I solved the problem by my self.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I solved the problem by my self.
The problem is that local spark(Maven version) did not know the information of hive on our cluster.

The solution is very simple.

Just add following codes on your source code.
`conf.set("spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession", "true")`
`System.setProperty("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://hostname:serviceport")`

It works!
Let's play with spark.